# Generating time slots in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have Id, StartDateTime, EndDateTime in my DataFrame

**Example**

```python
Id      StartDateTime                   EndDateTime
165     2017-06-05 12:45:14             2017-06-07 21:00:01  # Goes on for 2 days
166     2017-06-05 14:02:00             2017-06-05 14:22:45  # starts at 14:02 and ends at 14:22 (20 mmns)
```

I want to split the total difference into 4 buckets (6 hrs each) and day. (Data in minutes)

```python
Id        Day     00 - 06      06 - 12     12 - 18    18 - 24 
165       MON     0            0           314        360
165       TUE     360          360         360        360
165       WED     360          360         360        180
166       WED     0            0           20         0
```

I tried with `"datetime.timedelta"` to create time series but I couldnot achieve it for multiple days and time buckets. Any easy way in Spark (pySpark)?

My Code snippet

```python
myDf = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (34, 30, "2016-07-02 12:01:40", "2016-07-02 14:01:40"), (184, 32, "2016-07-03 12:21:23", "2016-07-07 12:01:40")
    ]).toDF(["itemid", "eventid", "startTime", "endTime"])
    .withColumn("startTime", col("startTime").cast("timestamp"))
)
myDf = myDf.withColumn("endTime", col("endTime").cast("timestamp"))
timeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
timeFormat = (F.unix_timestamp('endTime', format=timeFormat) - F.unix_timestamp('startTime', format=timeFormat))
myDf = myDf.withColumn("Trip Duration", timeFormat)
myDf = myDf.withColumn("Day" , date_format('startTime', 'E'))
myDf.show()
```

Comment: please share what you've tried too.

Comment: difficult to do with spark ... i think you should try udfs

Comment: I have updated code till i could calculate the difference and day for the starting time. But next step i couldnt move on.